# array is not printed here what to do

Tags: python

```py
def printAllRootToKnodePaths(root, k, arr=[]):
    if root is None:
        return False

    if root.data == k:
        arr.append(root.data)
        return True
    leftTree = printAllRootToKnodePaths(root.left, k)
    if leftTree:
        arr.append(root.data)
        print(arr)

        return True
    rightTree = printAllRootToKnodePaths(root.right, k)
    if rightTree:
        arr.append(root.data)
        return True
    # if printAllRootToKnodePaths:

    # print(arr)
    return False
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverfow! Please tel us what is your question? How do you call your function? What are the arguments?

Comment: See this: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)